# Try-catch not working as expected in Puppeteer-Cluster (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I have a simple Puppeteer-Cluster code written in NodeJS:

```
require("dotenv").config();

(async () => {
    // Create a cluster with 2 workers
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
    });

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: link }) => {
        let response =  await page.goto(link);
        statusCode = response.status();
        var finalUrl = "";
        try{
            await page.waitForNavigation();
            finalUrl = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
        } catch(error){
            finalUrl = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
        }
    });
    cluster.queue(some_random_link);
    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();
```

If the try block is having some error, like a timeout, then the catch block is not being run. The page is simply terminated.

**NOTE : When I run the same code using just normal Puppeteer, I have no issues. The issue is specifically with Puppeteer-Cluster.**